# Exchange 2013 ServerSide Event-Handler for Message-Flagging / Followup possible?

Tags: exchange-server

Is it possible to hook up some managed code into Exchange 2013 which is triggered when an E-Mail is flagged via Outlook or OWA?

I've been fiddling around with transport-agents, but they seem to get invoked only on Mail-Transport events, which is not enough, because the E-Mail won't get through the transport-pipeline when being flagged by some user.

Thanks for any help!
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Glen answered this on the MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0193a51-3347-48cf-896d-563901c383f9/serverside-eventhandler-for-flagevent-possible?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment